# Looping through child nodes

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Here is my sample XML:

```xml
<root>
  <Countries>
    <Country Name="USA">
        <MyFilters>
            <Filter>aaa</Filter>
            <Filter>bbb</Filter>
            <Filter>ccc</Filter>
            <Filter>ddd</Filter>
        </MyFilters>
    </Country>
  </Countries>
</root>
```

I am trying to loop through each `<Filter>` tag and use its value - "aaa", "bbb", … for my subsequent process in PowerShell. I am using XPath to access these values.

Here is my script:

```psh
[xml]$config_xml = Get-Content $config_path
$Country = $config_xml.selectnodes('/root/Countries/Country[@Name = "USA"]/MyFilters')
foreach ($Filter in $Country) {
  Write-Host $Filter.InnerText
}
```

But this is outputting me all the `<Filter>` values in one single line like this: `aaa bbb ccc ddd`. How do I use my XPath to fetch one filter at a time? Or is there a way to convert this output to PowerShell array object which I can loop again?

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath query returns the `<MyFilters>` node, not its child nodes, so the `InnerText` is the text content of that node (i.e. all child nodes combined).

Simply add another step to reference `Filter` elements if you want to loop through one `Filter` at a time :

```
/root/Countries/Country[@Name = "USA"]/MyFilters/Filter
```

or in case child element of `MyFilters` may have various names, you can use `*` :

```
/root/Countries/Country[@Name = "USA"]/MyFilters/*
```

Just some notes. `child` is the default axis in XPath, so `/child::node()` is the same as just `/node()`. And then `node()` returns all type of nodes (element, text, comment, etc), so `*` maybe more suitable here since you only want to return element nodes.

Answer (score 2):

v3+

```
## Replace me with
#[xml]$config_xml = Get-Content $config_path
[xml]$config_xml = @'
<root>
  <Countries>
    <Country Name="USA">
        <MyFilters>
            <Filter>aaa</Filter>
            <Filter>bbb</Filter>
            <Filter>ccc</Filter>
            <Filter>ddd</Filter>
        </MyFilters>
    </Country>
  </Countries>
</root>
'@

($config_xml.root.Countries.Country| Where-Object Name -EQ USA).MyFilters.Filter
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the XML content like this - [xml]$config_xml = Get-Content $config_path and storing it in XML object. Could you please tell me what is happening in your example.? And how do i use my XML file path here?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use your script, but getting this error now.. Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:17 char:50
+ ($config_xml.root.Countries.Country| Where-Object <<<<  Name -EQ "USA").MyFilters.Filter
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution for this, just sharing here if anyone needs this.

I used child::node() to fetch all the child nodes and then looped on that.

```
$Country = $config_xml.selectnodes('/root/Countries/Country[@Name = "USA"]/MyFilters/child::node()')
```